# Request the same webpage as seen in webbrowser

Tags: python-3.x, request, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some webpage, but I'm encountering with the problem that the page content is different from what I'm seeing in Firefox

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sareb.es/es_ES/inmuebles"
with requests.get(url, verify = False) as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file.content, "html.parser")
soup.find_all("h3")
```

I want to scrape the prices, which are in h3 tags, but the output is not showing them with `soup.find_all("h3")`.

Is there any way to retrieve the "same" webpage?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use requests for json response, create a loop with the page number to get more results. Total page is 1217.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.sareb.es/dynamic/assets/json?"


params = {
  "lang": "en_US",
  "page": "1",
  "orderField": "score",
  "orderDirection": "DESC",
  "compId": "7aa1f42482964610VgnVCMServera5ecbf0aRCRD",
  "rtbPage": "Home > Inmuebles",
  "compId": "7aa1f42482964610VgnVCMServera5ecbf0aRCRD"

}

headers = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36",
  "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "5618a1c8-9d8e-4a88-95a8-2eef4c2b3455",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}



r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, verify=False)
d = r.json()

results = (d['result']['assetsPage']['content'])

for result in results:
  print(result['type'], result['price'], result['city'], result['district'])
```

Results:

```
Country House 281.000 € Sueca Valencia/València
Country House To consult Moaña Pontevedra
Country House 152.000 € Corcos Valladolid
Country House 36.000 € Alcalà de Xivert Castellón/Castelló
Office 130.800 € Sagunto/Sagunt Valencia/València
Office 643.370 € Valencia Valencia/València
Office 646.495 € Valencia Valencia/València
Office 3.100 € Valencia Valencia/València
Office 144.700 € / 1.070 € Palmas de Gran Canaria (Las) Palmas, Las
Office 326.400 € / 1.635 € Murcia Murcia
Offices From 60.000 € Colmenar Viejo Madrid
Office 519.300 € / 2.564 € Alicante/Alacant Alicante/Alacant
Office To consult Palma de Mallorca Balears, Illes
Office 97.000 € Santa Lucía de Tirajana Palmas, Las
Offices From 444.200 € Sevilla Sevilla
Offices From 34.700 € Villamayor Salamanca
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why not using those parameters wasn’t working?

Comment: You can see that the request url is different. The data was sent from the the json to the front end. So you can actually send a request to the back for a json response which save you time looping through the front

Comment: I would like to ask how did you find that you can make json request to that page, if it's possible

Comment: these dynamic website usually make a query to the back end and render it in the front end. if you monitor the network tab in chrome development tool, you can see http requests that is send from your browser. from that, you can find that the browser is actually make a request to the website json endpoint. Hope this help